Cannot determine pins to use when connecting 3 SPI devices to Pi 5
I am trying to connect 3 SPI devices to my pi 5, they are all RFID-RC522 modules and so they all have the same device id, so I put them on separate busses.
I researched and selected these three overlays for the /boot/firmware/overlays/config.txt file:
overlay=       pins     cs pin
spi2-1cs-pi5   1-3      0
spi3-1cs-pi5   5-7      4
spi5-1cs-pi5   13-15    12

I now have these /dev entries:
spidev10.0
spidev2.0
spidev3.0
spidev5.0

I don't know what spidev10.0 is, it was there before.
The pin numbers above came from the /boot/firmware/overlays/README file where I selected my overlays to activate, but I don't quite get what I'm doing here, re:

I've never used a chip select pin before today, do I need to connect it?
It's great to say pins 1-3 and 0 but which pins connect which way
The pinouts I can find for Pi 5 don't line up with the numbers from the overlay file, don't have a pin 0 and some of the pins specified are for power
Information specific to the Pi 5 is difficult to get online.
The modules have these pins: sda, sdk, mosi, miso, irq, gnd, reset, 3.3v

I'm guessing I can leave IRQ and reset tied low, but that still leaves me sda, sdk, mosi, miso and NO cs pin on the module, what connections should I make for these three overlays?

Read a SPI wiki to get an understanding of how SPI works.

Thanks @Joan, but as you may see if you’d bothered to read the questions it’s mosty about Pi, pin allocations and overlays. If you’ve nothing useful to say that’s fine too, thanks.

Your first question indicates a lack of understanding of SPI and without details of what you are attempting to connect is unanswerable. The Pi documentation assumes an understanding of BCM numbering which is quite well documented.

NOTE SPI2 (pins 0,1) is effectively unusable on most Pi due to conflicts with (undocumented) internal connections.

I suggest you purchase the Raspberry Pi Ltd. Pi5 documentation (although it is possible to download a soft copy on the Pi itself using Bookshelf).

@milliways, Okay, thank you, I'll research BCM numbering and Bookshelf. In terms of what I'm attempting to connect, I was clear it is three x RFID-RC522 modules. Thanks for the pointers.

I have never seen a MFRC522 without a CS, although most have poor documentation so it is unclear and virtually all the online examples have problems (at least with the common modules). Note your comment about having the same id is misleading - that isn't how SPI works. There are many examples of using multiple MFRC522 modules on a single bus, including in MagPi. If unfamiliar with SPI this isn't the best chip to start.

I could switch to the PN532 boards where I can use UART or I2C without cutting traces, but I'll have to look for a new software driver, I may try. I see now that I could connect all 3 to the same SPI, but I am likely to run into the issue here https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=195628 I suspect the CS is the SDA, just from searching.

Okay, I learned something about SPI as I was confusing it with I2C. However for this project I switched to UART and had a more fun time from there with fewer wires and pins. Thanks!
